# jQuery to loop through table rows and cells, where checkbox is checked, then concatenate

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows. there are several columns in the table with checkboxes. I need to loop through each of the checkboxes, where it is checked concatenate/join the input from that particular cell to other inputs from the same row.

you can see a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/10/

How can I, in addition to looping through the row, loop through each `<td>` once I have this `<td>` how can I look for an input whose name starts with `x` in that td. once found concatenate / join the input from that  to the inputs in the row.

I hope that makes sense.

essentially:
I want to join the (family) to the (size) to the (grade) where family and grade are on the same row, and there are several sizes on each row. each result must be written to the TD currently being processed.

I have got up to this point but have got stuck:

```
function createcodes(){
    alert('running');
    //run through each row
    $('.authors-list tr').each(function(){
         //processing this row
            //how to process each cell(table td) where there is checkbox
        $($(this).find('input[name^="line"]').val(

            $('$(this).find('input[name^="family"]'').val() + ' ' + // common input(family) on row, use for all table cells(td)
            $('#$(this).find('input[name^="size"]'').val() + ', ' + // this cells input called size, unique to this cell only
            $('#$(this).find('input[name^="grade"]'').val() // common input(grade) on row, use for all table cells(td)
          );
          // end of cell row processing
      });
        //end of rows processing
}
```

Thanks as always.

http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/10/

my html is:

```
<table class="authors-list" border=1 id="ordertable">
 <tr>
     <td ><input type="text" id="product1" name="product1" class="rounded" value="38114CR"></td>
     <td ><input type="text" size='5' id="qty1" name="qty1" class="rounded" value="10"/></td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h09_1" name="h09_1" checked class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_09" name="line_1_09" >
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_09" name="size_1_09" value="09">

    </td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h12_1" name="h12_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_12" name="line_1_12" value="">
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_12" name="size_1_12" value="12">
    </td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h15_1" name="h15_1" checked class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_15" name="line_1_15" >
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_15" name="size_1_15" value="15">
    </td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="cubespercheck_1" id="cubespercheck_1" value="0" size=5></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="skufamily_1" id="skufamily_1" value="38114"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="skugrade_1" id="skugrade_1" value="cr"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="continue" value="continue">
```

keep in mind there are multiple rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I've updated your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/QS56z/18/

Also, I've changed two `^=` to `*=`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

And note the `:checked` selector. See http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
function createcodes() {

    //run through each row
    $('.authors-list tr').each(function (i, row) {

        // reference all the stuff you need first
        var $row = $(row),
            $family = $row.find('input[name*="family"]'),
            $grade = $row.find('input[name*="grade"]'),
            $checkedBoxes = $row.find('input:checked');

        $checkedBoxes.each(function (i, checkbox) {
            // assuming you layout the elements this way, 
            // we'll take advantage of .next()
            var $checkbox = $(checkbox),
                $line = $checkbox.next(),
                $size = $line.next();

            $line.val(
                $family.val() + ' ' + $size.val() + ', ' + $grade.val()
            );

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Terry, this make me so angry. so simple an answer. Thanks so so much!

Comment: @Smudger You're welcome. I assume this fits what you described? Is this fit to be marked as an answer?

Comment: 100% correct. sorry my connectivity is dodgy currently. :-) Thanks again Terry!

Comment: Hi Terry, this is awesome but not 100% correct. on the fiddle, it is not taking the size of the current <td>, it is taking the first <td> each time. how can we correct that to take the current <td> it is referencing. in addition how can I get this to only work where the checkbox is checked? Thanks again.

Comment: When you say "*only where the checkbox is checked*", does that mean **for each row, all three checkboxes must be checked, else do nothing for that row**?

Comment: Hi Terry, no. only if the checkbox in that cell is checked, then populate the input. so if you look at desired output on the fiddle, 12 is excluded as not checked. 09 and 15 are processed. Thanks Terry

Comment: Terry, you are awesome! Thanks so SO much. will get my head around this as homework. Thanks again and go well...

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. jQuery selectors can be very powerful traversal tools, the docs are very worth reading. :)

Comment: Thanks Terry, I will do. Reading not the issue so much as the brain :-) go well and thanks again.

Comment: OMG, people in pure JS it would be 80% less coding and you get a function with 50% faster execution. C'mon!

Comment: TomeeNS, I wouldn't be surprised if that's the case. However, 1) the question was tagged as jquery, 2) there's no background on what browsers need to be supported and what cross-browser scripting is required, and 3) I would expect figures to be backed by benchmarks instead of an over-reaction. I'm open to enlightenment if you have any jsperf.com benchmarks to back it up.

Anyway, I don't think anyone here actually said they are against "pure JS" nor claiming jQuery is less code or faster than a "vanilla JS" solution. Nor do I think the focus should be shifted away from the original question.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
function createcodes() {

    $('.authors-list tr').each(function () {
        //processing this row
        //how to process each cell(table td) where there is checkbox
        $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function () {

             // it is checked, your code here...
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will this look at all checkboxes or just checked ones? I need it for just checked checkboxes... Thanks Palash

Comment: Hi Palash, I have updated my attempt at a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/12/ please can you guide me further... thanks.