# How can I iterate through the items of a table using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through the items of a table using JQuery at the same time I need to check if a checkbox is checked or not. I am using the following code:

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    var name = $(".name").html();
    var city = $(".city").html();

    alert(name + " " +  city);
});
```

And the html structure of my `tr` in which the inputs are:

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="prove" class="prove"></td>
   <td class="name">Peter</td>
   <td class="city">New York</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="prove" class="prove"></td>
   <td class="name">Andrew</td>
   <td class="city">Madrid</td>
</tr>
```

But I am getting always the first element on the output (when both checkbox are checked):

```
Peter New York
Peter New York
```

How can I make my function goes to the next `tr` instead of always show the data of the first one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171607/1314677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.html()` with Class selector, it will always retrieve the HTML content from the first element of the matched elements.

You need to iterate in current element context of `this`, use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `tr` element then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the desired `td`'s.

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find(".name").html();
    var city = tr.find(".city").html();
    alert(name + " " +  city);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function() {

var obj = $(".prove:checked").map(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find('td.name').text();
    var city = tr.find('td.city').text();
    return name + ' ' + city;
}).get();
console.log(obj);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="prove" class="prove"></td>
   <td class="name">Peter</td>
   <td class="city">New York</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="prove" class="prove"></td>
   <td class="name">Andrew</td>
   <td class="city">Madrid</td>
</tr>
  </table>

<button>click</button>
```

Comment: It should be better if you combine your both options in one answer instead of two different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.siblings()` in jquery and `$(this)` to get current object in jquery

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).parent().siblings('.name').text();
    var city = $(this).parent().siblings('.city').text();
     alert(name + '' + city);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var name = tr.find(".name").html();
    var city = tr.find(".city").html();

    alert(name + " " +  city);
});
```

Comment: It should be `tr = $(this).parents('tr')` as `checkbox` immediate parent is `td`