# jQuery: Grabbing All Input Values within Static and Dynamically Created Form Rows and Appending All to Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a relatively new developer and have been stuck on this for days now. So basically, I'm making a nutrition-tracker app (like MyFitnessPal). I've got a form for meal inputs, with an 'Add Row' button for multiple items within each meal (ex. steak, potatoes and garlic bread all being separate rows on the input form - each having its own nutrition information). The form contains only one line by default (static), but the user can click the 'Add Row' button and create dynamic rows below the first to add more items (each row gets a new ID, and each input field gets a new ID as well).

**Desired Outcome:** When the user clicks submit, all values within each row should be grabbed, and then appended to the 'Meal Log' card below the form, all within one 'Meal'. The form then automatically clears and deletes the extra dynamic rows, allowing the user to start adding more food items for Meal 2.

**The problem:** I cannot figure out how to grab multiple dynamically created form rows, and their dynamically created input values. I tried adding ID's and classes to these elements, and I think I need to do some type of for loop, but not sure how to do it, and can't wrap my mind around it.. Currently, I can grab the input values from the first row and append them, but it ignores the other dynamic rows.

Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Submit button
  var count = 1;
  $("#submit").on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $header = $("<h5 class='text-left' style='font-weight: bold;'>Meal " + count++ + "</h5>");
    $("#meals").append($header);

    var food = $("#foodName").val().trim();
    var calories = $("#calories").val().trim();
    var protein = $("#protein").val().trim();
    var fat = $("#fat").val().trim();
    var carbs = $("#carbs").val().trim();

    var firstRow = {
      food: food,
      calories: calories,
      protein: protein,
      fat: fat,
      carbs: carbs
    };

    $("#meals").append("<tr class='row text-center'><td class='col-sm-3'>" + food + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + calories + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + protein + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + fat + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + carbs + "</td><br>");

    $("#foodName").val("");
    $("#calories").val("");
    $("#protein").val("");
    $("#fat").val("");
    $("#carbs").val("");

    $(".dynamic").val("");
    $(".dynamicRow").remove();

  });

  // database.ref().on("child_added", function (childSnapshot) {

  //     var name = childSnapshot.val().name;
  //     var dest = childSnapshot.val().dest;
  //     var fTrain = childSnapshot.val().fTrain;
  //     var freq = childSnapshot.val().freq;
  //     var freq = childSnapshot.val().freq;

  //     $("#table > tbody").prepend("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + dest + "</td><td>" + freq + "</td><td>" + nextTrain + "</td><td>" + minsToTrain + "</td></tr>");

  // });

  // Add Row Button
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addRow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    newRow.addClass("row dynamicRow");

    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control dynamic" id="foodName' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control dynamic" id="calories' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control dynamic" id="protein' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control dynamic" id="fat' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control dynamic" id="carbs' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-1 dynamic"><span id="clickFA"><i class="ibtnDel fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x trash"></span></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#inputTable").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1;
  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url('../styles/img/gravel.png');
}


/* Navbar */

#navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px;
}

#brand {
  background: rgb(10, 177, 93);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#navBtn {
  background: black;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#goalCard {
  margin: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#dailyGoal {
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#userForm {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

.trash {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mealLog {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#logHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#title {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

#submit {
  float: left;
}

#addRow {
  float: right;
}

#motto {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#form {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px gray;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#addMeal {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px !important;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px; */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: red; */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#footerSpan {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>BiteTracker</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Firebase JavaScript Link -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="brand"><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i> BiteTracker</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./profile.html">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./signin.html">Sign-Out</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./foodapi.html">RecipeSearch</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Site Body -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Remaining Card -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-sm-12" id="goalCard">
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul id="dailyGoal">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Your Daily Goal:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Calories: 2000</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Protein: 100g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Fat: 75g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Carbs: 200g</li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="remaining">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Remaining:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Calories: 1500</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Protein: 50g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Fat: 20g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Carbs: 50g</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- User Meal Submit -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card bg-light text-dark" id="userForm">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="addMeal">Add Meal</h2>
          <table id="inputTable" class="table order-list">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Carbs (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="row" id="staticRow">
                <td class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" id="foodName" name="foodName" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="calories" name="calories" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="protein" name="protein" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="fat" name="fat" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="carbs" name="carbs" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addRow" value="Add Row">Add
                        Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Meal Log -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card col-sm-12 bg-light text-dark" id="mealLog">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="logHeader">Meal Log</h2>
          <table id="logTable" class="table order-list text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3" id="foodEntry">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="caloriesEntry">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="proteinEntry">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="fatEntry">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="carbsEntry">Carbs (g)</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="meals">
              <td></td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="footer bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <span id="footerSpan">BiteTracker &copy; 2018</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="../public/js/firebase.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So as you can see if you run the code, if you add a second row and enter data into the input fields in both rows, and then submit, only the top row appends to the Meal Log below under Meal 1. I need all rows (static + all dynamic rows) to be grabbed and then appended. Any help on this will greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are correct that you need to use a loop to go through each row. Check out this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171300/jquery-to-loop-through-table-rows-and-cells-where-checkob-is-checked-concatena which does something similar to what you are asking and ask further questions if you still need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class on the row and and also add classes on the input.
Then iterate over all the rows by class and fetch inputs by the class.
I have added classes which you may want to rename.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Submit button
  var count = 1;
  $("#submit").on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $header = $("<h5 class='text-left' style='font-weight: bold;'>Meal " + count++ + "</h5>");
    $("#meals").append($header);

    $(".food").each(function(index) {

      var food = $(this).find( ".a" ).val().trim();
      var calories = $(this).find( ".b" ).val().trim();
      var protein = $(this).find( ".c" ).val().trim();
      var fat = $(this).find( ".d" ).val().trim();
      var carbs = $(this).find( ".e" ).val().trim();

      var firstRow = {
        food: food,
        calories: calories,
        protein: protein,
        fat: fat,
        carbs: carbs
      };

      $("#meals").append("<tr class='row text-center'><td class='col-sm-3'>" + food + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + calories + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + protein + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + fat + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + carbs + "</td><br>");

    });

    $("#foodName").val("");
    $("#calories").val("");
    $("#protein").val("");
    $("#fat").val("");
    $("#carbs").val("");

    $(".dynamic").val("");
    $(".dynamicRow").remove();

  });

  // database.ref().on("child_added", function (childSnapshot) {

  //     var name = childSnapshot.val().name;
  //     var dest = childSnapshot.val().dest;
  //     var fTrain = childSnapshot.val().fTrain;
  //     var freq = childSnapshot.val().freq;
  //     var freq = childSnapshot.val().freq;

  //     $("#table > tbody").prepend("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + dest + "</td><td>" + freq + "</td><td>" + nextTrain + "</td><td>" + minsToTrain + "</td></tr>");

  // });

  // Add Row Button
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addRow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    newRow.addClass("row dynamicRow food");

    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control a dynamic" id="foodName' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control b dynamic" id="calories' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control c dynamic" id="protein' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control d dynamic" id="fat' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control e dynamic" id="carbs' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-1 dynamic"><span id="clickFA"><i class="ibtnDel fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x trash"></span></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#inputTable").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1;
  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url('../styles/img/gravel.png');
}


/* Navbar */

#navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px;
}

#brand {
  background: rgb(10, 177, 93);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#navBtn {
  background: black;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#goalCard {
  margin: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#dailyGoal {
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#userForm {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

.trash {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mealLog {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#logHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#title {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

#submit {
  float: left;
}

#addRow {
  float: right;
}

#motto {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#form {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px gray;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#addMeal {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px !important;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px; */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: red; */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#footerSpan {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>BiteTracker</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Firebase JavaScript Link -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="brand"><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i> BiteTracker</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./profile.html">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./signin.html">Sign-Out</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./foodapi.html">RecipeSearch</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Site Body -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Remaining Card -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-sm-12" id="goalCard">
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul id="dailyGoal">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Your Daily Goal:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Calories: 2000</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Protein: 100g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Fat: 75g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Carbs: 200g</li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="remaining">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Remaining:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Calories: 1500</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Protein: 50g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Fat: 20g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2">Carbs: 50g</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- User Meal Submit -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card bg-light text-dark" id="userForm">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="addMeal">Add Meal</h2>
          <table id="inputTable" class="table order-list">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Carbs (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="row food" id="staticRow">
                <td class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" id="foodName" name="foodName" class="a form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="calories" name="calories" class="b form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="protein" name="protein" class="c form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="fat" name="fat" class="d form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="carbs" name="carbs" class="e form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addRow" value="Add Row">Add
                        Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Meal Log -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card col-sm-12 bg-light text-dark" id="mealLog">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="logHeader">Meal Log</h2>
          <table id="logTable" class="table order-list text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3" id="foodEntry">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="caloriesEntry">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="proteinEntry">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="fatEntry">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="carbsEntry">Carbs (g)</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="meals">
              <td></td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="footer bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <span id="footerSpan">BiteTracker &copy; 2018</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="../public/js/firebase.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are a Godsend, thank you so much. I knew we were close, just couldn't wrap my mind around grabbing all dynamic inputs from the dynamic rows. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Right away one of the biggest issues I see is that your dynamically created form fields are using ID attributes as identifiers and not classes. The ID attribute should be unique across a page.

Heres a pen with some small js changes that hopefully get you on the right foot: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxQEdY

The loop in question:

```
  $('.inputRow').each(function(i, row) {
      var food = $(row).find(".foodName").val().trim();
      var calories = $(row).find(".calories").val().trim();
      var protein = $(row).find(".protein").val().trim();
      var fat = $(row).find(".fat").val().trim();
      var carbs = $(row).find(".carbs").val().trim();

      $("#meals").append("<tr class='row text-center'><td class='col-sm-3'>" + food + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + calories + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + protein + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + fat + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + carbs + "</td><br>");
    });
```